# Data Type Conversions with SQL and sqlalchemy.types

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes

I am creating a table in SQL and sending data to it though some helper functions using python. For my function (call it: submit_to_sql), I send the dataframe, table name, and the data types. That data is then in the table on SQL. However, for one of my columns, I am having trouble figuring out which datatype I should provide.

The values I would like to pass are in the form of a decimal, 00.00. There are 2 significant digits with (in theory) unlimited characteristics before it. What is the correct data type that I should assign my column within my script, such that on SQL, the values display properly?

This is how I defined it at first, but it rounded the values:

```
# Define Column types in my script
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import types as types
#... skipping some code for brevity
'Column': types.Numeric()

--Create MyTable in SQL
CREATE TABLE [Table].[TableName](
[Column] [dec] NULL
)
```

Comment: By "SQL" you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I mean Microsoft SQL Server.